# Core Data best practice to fetch to-many objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My core data model look something like this:

```
Song
=====
name
duration
album

inPlaylists (to many relationship)

Playlist
========
title

songs (to many relationship)
```

each `Playlist` has a many-to-many relationship with `Song` and vice versa.

I have a playlists view controller that present a list of `Playlist` objects.
To populate the playlists tableview I use the regular way of creating a `NSFetchRequest` and use it with a `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Playlist"];
request.predicate = nil;
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]];
request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

once the user tap a playlist row, I want to push another view controller that present the playlist's songs.

My question is how to get the playlists song?
I know I have the playlist object so I can get an array of it's song by calling `playlist.songs.allObjects` but i'm not sure how efficient that is and also I want to use `NSFetchedResultsController` so I can enjoy all its delegate methods for updating the tableview.

So what is the best practice for such a basic scenario?

btw as u can see the Playlist entity doesn't have `playlistId` property, I let core data handle the keys, so if possible I prefer not adding this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display all songs of a selected playlist in a table view, you would create a 
fetched results controller (as you did for the playlist table), but 
with a fetch requests for the `Song` entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Song"];
```

and a predicate using the inverse relationship from "Song" to "Playlist":

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY inPlaylists = %@",
                                          selectedPlaylist];
```

The "ANY" keyword is necessary because "inPlaylists" is a to-many relationship.

Comment: that's great thanks! one more question, if the relationship from song to playlist was 'To-One' (i.e. song can have only one playlist) what should be the predicate now?

Comment: @user3149567: Just omit the ANY: `... "inPlaylist = @", selectedPlaylist]` .